# Manually trigger a database/system error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Is it possible to manually trigger a database/system error, to see and demonstrate the impact and result of using and not using commits?
Is there one for MariaDB?

Comment: What kind of error exactly?

Comment: Like a system crash or something like this. Just to show what happens when you use commit and rollback correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ways to generate an error or failure (ordered approximately by severity, and probably missing some):

- execute a statement that will result in an error (e.g. insert an already existing primary key to get a key violation)
- use [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) to raise an explicit exception (like in other programming languages):

  > SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error. SIGNAL provides error information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or to the client.
- MariaDB has transaction timeouts, so wait until you reach a [timeout limit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/transaction-timeouts/) to get:

  > ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
- use [`KILL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/kill.html) to terminate a specific connection or query:

  > - KILL CONNECTION is the same as KILL with no modifier: It terminates the connection associated with the given processlist_id, after terminating any statement the connection is executing.
  > - KILL QUERY terminates the statement the connection is currently executing, but leaves the connection itself intact.
- [Kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_(command)) the mariadb process from your os

It should not matter what method you use - a transaction that is not committed will eventually be rolled back. The last two methods can also interrupt non-transactional operations like `alter table`, and might leave a table or database corrupted.